# appyling a function for all relevant tags - jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, attr

I'm figuring jQuery out at the moment. there are 6 `<li>` tags with custom attr called `data-index="x"` (x is just numbers 0 to 6).Basically I'm trying to apply for loop rather than writing it over and over yet I've failed so far.

here is the code:

```
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    var m = 'i*-40' + 'px'
    $('li[data-index="i"] p')
    .css( {backgroundPosition: "-150px m"} )
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 m)"}, {duration:300})
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-150px m)"}, {duration:300})
    });
}
```

Comment: `$('li[data-index="i"] p')` should be `$('li[data-index="'+i+'"] p')`

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have missed something obvious, but: what are you asking us to help with?

Comment: updated the full answer, according to your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables inside strings aren't magically evaluated.

You should use something like

```
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    var m = i*-40 + 'px';
    $('li[data-index="' + i + '"] p')
    .css( {backgroundPosition: "-150px " + m} )
    .on('mouseover', function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"0 " + m}, 300)
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"-150px " + m}, 300)
    });
}
```

Comment: it's {backgroundPosition:"x-axis y-axis"}, not suppossed to be added.

Comment: @ksmsk In JavaScript, `+` operator concatenates strings (among other uses).

Answer (score 0):

Change your whole implementation like bellow

```
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    var m = i*40; //getting m as number not string
    $('li[data-index="'+i+'"] p')
    .css( {backgroundPosition: (-150+m) + 'px'} ) // add two numbers & then append to string
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:(0+m)+'px'}, {duration:300})
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:(-150 +m)+'px'}, {duration:300})
    });
}
```

I got a bit confused with `-` sign in line `var m = i*40;` So just check that once.

Comment: Single quotes are missing inside.

Comment: still doesn't work. Is there something wrong with the math? I was trying to get var m as 0, -40px, -80px, -120px, -160px, -200px.

Comment: @ksmsk updated my answer, you were not adding the value of `m` to `-150px`

Comment: @ksmsk did you get your answer?